# Can i convert a known checksum back to hex?

Tags: checksum

Dunno if this is a stupid question but is there a way to retain data (or hex) from a known checksum. I was reading some serial EEPROM and accidently hit the BLANK button. I know the checksum 142h but is there anyway to convert this back?? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. The number of distinct checksums in all commonly-used checksum schemes is much less than the number of possible states mapping to those checksums.